# bike for surfing: hybrid vs beach cruiser vs fat

Tags: product-rec

I’m looking for a bike to take my surfboard (6’6”) to local surf breaks.  I would be biking 1-4 miles on a concrete or asphalt beach path that gets some sand on it.  What’s a good bike for this purpose? Hybrid? Beach Cruiser? Fat?

Comment: 1-4 miles on an asphalt path - honestly it doesn't really matter so long as you can find a way to carry the board. Go with whatever is the best fit/most convenient/most likely to withstand sand and salt.

Comment: Seems like a trailer would be a good way to safely carry move a surfboard. Any of those bikes would work with a trailer. Is a trailer a possibility?

Comment: Definitely a trailer.  Carrying a surfboard on a bicycle?  A gust of wind at the wrong time and next thing you know you're "bicycle jousting" with unaware pedestrians... :-O

Comment: Get one that is less trendy, therefore less likely to be stolen while you're catching waves.

Answer (score 6):

All of those bikes would be fine, at least for a while. You can find pictures of board carriers on all those bikes. 
[image: Surfboard Carrier on Bike Cruiser]

The problem is that salt water destroys bikes. It's why beach cruisers are as cheap and simple as possible, if they actually get used by the ocean they will either require washing or rust out in a year or so.

A Fat bike would be a really good choice if riding on the beach itself is part of your plans. You can't really ride a beach cruiser in deep soft sand. However, fat bikes are more expensive and you'll need to be diligent about washing the bike if you want to keep your investment. Theft is also an issue, fat bikes are more likely to be stolen than a cheap rusty beach cruiser.

Comment: Concur - some ugly cheap old 26" MTB converted to single speed would be ideal for this task.

Comment: Brakes are good. I like brakes.

Comment: Coaster brakes - when you pedal  backwards there is an internal drum brake in the hub.